# Trim trailing mysql group_concat from large generated query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I got most of this working but I'm now down to trimming the last bit off and I'm stuck.

The plan is to remove the last UNION ALL from this output statement so I can copy the entire thing into MySQL and get my output. Yes, I know a SPROC or Prepared Statement would be best, but security frowns on this and we are audited for these.

The reason for this query is I have multiple databases that have different sys_log000x tables. Some go from 0000 to 0005 or 0006, others can go as high as 9999, so I need a query that will aggregate all the tables into a useable format.

Here is the query used to build the full query:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1024*1024*1024; 
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT a.`table`, a.parm1 AS `updatedColumn(s)`, a.parm2 AS `DDLtype`, SUM(a.qtyReady) AS `qtyReady`, SUM(a.qtyQueued) AS `qtyQueued`, SUM(a.qtyProcessed) AS `qtyProcessed`, SUM(a.qtyTransferred) AS `qtyTransferred`, SUM(a.qtyError) AS `qtyError`, a.sys_updated_by AS `updatedBy`, SUM(COUNT) AS `TtlCount` FROM (",
             (GROUP_CONCAT("SELECT ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN ",
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN ",
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,", 
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM ",
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           " ", 
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0", " WHERE ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY ",
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`table`,", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`parm1`,", 
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`parm2`,",
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`sys_updated_by UNION ALL`"  
                           SEPARATOR ' '))
               ')a GROUP BY a.`table`, a.`parm1`,  a.`parm2`,  a.`sys_updated_by` ORDER BY `TtlCount` DESC LIMIT 40;')
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema !='mysql' AND table_name LIKE 'sys_log0%'
```

Here's the output trimmed down:

> `` SELECT a.`table`, a.parm1 AS `updatedColumn(s)`, a.parm2 AS `DDLtype`, SUM(a.qtyReady) AS `qtyReady`, SUM(a.qtyQueued) AS `qtyQueued`, SUM(a.qtyProcessed) AS `qtyProcessed`, SUM(a.qtyTransferred) AS `qtyTransferred`, SUM(a.qtyError) AS `qtyError`, a.sys_updated_by AS `updatedBy`, SUM(COUNT) AS `TtlCount` FROM (SELECT sys_log00000.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(sys_log00000.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(sys_log00000.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00000.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00000.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00000.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00000.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00000.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,sys_log00000.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(sys_log00000.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM sys_log0000 sys_log00000 WHERE sys_log00000.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY sys_log00000.`table`,sys_log00000.`parm1`,sys_log00000.`parm2`,sys_log00000.`sys_updated_by` UNION ALL SELECT sys_log00010.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(sys_log00010.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(sys_log00010.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00010.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00010.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00010.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00010.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00010.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,sys_log00010.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(sys_log00010.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM sys_log0001 sys_log00010 WHERE sys_log00010.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY sys_log00010.`table`,sys_log00010.`parm1`,sys_log00010.`parm2`,sys_log00010.`sys_updated_by` UNION ALL SELECT sys_log00020.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(sys_log00020.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(sys_log00020.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00020.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00020.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00020.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00020.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00020.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,sys_log00020.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(sys_log00020.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM sys_log0002 sys_log00020 WHERE sys_log00020.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY sys_log00020.`table`,sys_log00020.`parm1`,sys_log00020.`parm2`,sys_log00020.`sys_updated_by` UNION ALL SELECT sys_log00030.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(sys_log00030.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(sys_log00030.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00030.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00030.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00030.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00030.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00030.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,sys_log00030.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(sys_log00030.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM sys_log0003 sys_log00030 WHERE sys_log00030.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY sys_log00030.`table`,sys_log00030.`parm1`,sys_log00030.`parm2`,sys_log00030.`sys_updated_by` UNION ALL SELECT sys_log00040.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(sys_log00040.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(sys_log00040.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00040.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00040.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00040.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00040.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00040.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,sys_log00040.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(sys_log00040.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM sys_log0004 sys_log00040 WHERE sys_log00040.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY sys_log00040.`table`,sys_log00040.`parm1`,sys_log00040.`parm2`,sys_log00040.`sys_updated_by` UNION ALL SELECT sys_log00050.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(sys_log00050.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(sys_log00050.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00050.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00050.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00050.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00050.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN sys_log00050.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,sys_log00050.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(sys_log00050.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM sys_log0005 sys_log00050 WHERE sys_log00050.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY sys_log00050.`table`,sys_log00050.`parm1`,sys_log00050.`parm2`,sys_log00050.`sys_updated_by` UNION ALL)a GROUP BY a.`table`, a.`parm1`,  a.`parm2`,  a.`sys_updated_by` ORDER BY `TtlCount` DESC LIMIT 40; ``

The last UNION ALL just before )a is what I'm trying to remove.

Any help or guidance you can provide would be awesome!

Comment: That is the punishment for splitting up the data into a bunch of identical tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily solve this problem by removing the `UNION ALL` from the last element in the `GROUP_CONCAT` and changing the SEPARATOR to `UNION ALL` i.e.

```
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT a.`table`, a.parm1 AS `updatedColumn(s)`, a.parm2 AS `DDLtype`, SUM(a.qtyReady) AS `qtyReady`, SUM(a.qtyQueued) AS `qtyQueued`, SUM(a.qtyProcessed) AS `qtyProcessed`, SUM(a.qtyTransferred) AS `qtyTransferred`, SUM(a.qtyError) AS `qtyError`, a.sys_updated_by AS `updatedBy`, SUM(COUNT) AS `TtlCount` FROM (",
             (GROUP_CONCAT("SELECT ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`table` AS 'table',LEFT(", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`parm1`,40) AS 'parm1',LEFT(", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`parm2`,40) AS 'parm2',SUM(CASE WHEN ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyReady`,SUM(CASE WHEN ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` LIKE 'queued%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyQueued`,SUM(CASE WHEN ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyProcessed`,SUM(CASE WHEN ",
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'transferred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyTransferred`,SUM(CASE WHEN ",
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`state` = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS `qtyError`,", 
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`sys_updated_by` AS 'sys_updated_by', COUNT(", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`sys_id`) AS `count` FROM ",
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           " ", 
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0", " WHERE ", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`queue` = 'text_index' GROUP BY ",
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`table`,", 
                           TABLE_NAME, 
                           "0.`parm1`,", 
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`parm2`,",
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           "0.`sys_updated_by`"  
                           SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '))
               ')a GROUP BY a.`table`, a.`parm1`,  a.`parm2`,  a.`sys_updated_by` ORDER BY `TtlCount` DESC LIMIT 40;')
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema !='mysql' AND table_name LIKE 'sys_log0%'
```

Comment: Thank you nick! And this is why I shouldn't write MySQL queries on Friday nights!!!